# Keep text colour inside tables and table/figure captions

Tags: floats, color, captions, environments

I have the following environment definition:

```
\newif\ifrev
\newenvironment{revision}{%
    \begingroup
        \revtrue%
        \color{blue}%
    }{%
        \revfalse%
    \endgroup
}
```

This environment simply colours all the text inside it blue and sets the `\ifrev` to true inside it.

In tables and figures inside this environment, the `\ifrev` value is preserved properly (i.e. an `\ifrev` statement evaluates to true if the figure/table is in a `revision` environment and false otherwise). However, the text colour of the captions and table entries is reset to black. For example:

```
\begin{document}
\lipsum[42]
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \ifrev{A}\else{a}\fi & b \\
        c & d
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding `\begin{revision}` and `\end{revision}` right after and before `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` correctly colours the paragraph blue and changes the lowercase a to uppercase A in the table, but keeps the text in the table and the captions black.

How do I also keep the blue colour inside tables and figures inside this environment?

Comment: `\begingroup` and `\revfalse\endgroup` are doing nothing as an environemnt is already a group so the setting is restored automatically. Figures are floating inserts that may be inserted in a region using different fonts and colours so they always normalise everything to document defaults. You could locally define `\normalcolor`  to blue (but then page headings for pages breaks within that scope will be blue

Comment: You could set up your captions etc. to use a custom colour which you set to `black` and then redefine to `blue` inside the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the comments, I have rewritten the environment definition as follows, which seems to function as I wanted it to:

```
\newenvironment{revision}{%
    \revtrue%
    \color{\revcolour}%
    \captionsetup*{font={color=\revcolour}}%
    \captionsetup*[sub]{font={color=\revcolour}}%
    \makeatletter%
    \let\oldtable\table%
    \def\table{\@ifnextchar[\table@i \table@ii}%
    \def\table@i[#1]{\oldtable[#1]\color{\revcolour}}%
    \def\table@ii{\oldtable\color{\revcolour}}%
    \makeatother%
}{}
```